# php creating count based on two keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$dinnerDetails` that looks like this

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "request_id" => "48"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "yes"
    "requestCount" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "request_id" => "51"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 3
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "request_id" => "65"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => null
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 3
  ]
  3 => array:7 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "yes"
    "requestCount" => 2
  ]
  4 => & array:7 [▼
    "request_id" => "52"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 2
  ]
]
```

You will notice that each subarray has `dinner_id` and `host_id`, if both these values exist then it means dinner has been confirmed. What i am trying to do is count the number of confirmed dinners. In an array above `dinner_id => 36` has been confirmed by 2 people and the same goes for `dinner_id` => 35,

I would like to add a new `key` in the sub array lets call it `confirmationCount` and put the confirmed count against it so that my output looks like this

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "request_id" => "48"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "yes"
    "requestCount" => 3
    "confirmationCount" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "request_id" => "51"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 3
    "confirmationCount" => 2
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "request_id" => "65"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => null
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 3
    "confirmationCount" => 2
  ]
  3 => array:8 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "yes"
    "requestCount" => 2
    "confirmationCount" => 2
  ]
  4 => & array:8 [▼
    "request_id" => "52"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "host_id" => "77"
    "new_dinner" => "no"
    "requestCount" => 2
    "confirmationCount" => 2
  ]
]
```

So to do this I wrote `foreach` loop twice, the first loop prepares the array and the second loop adds the count i need.

```
$dinnerDetails = array();
$lastDinnerDate = '';
$newDate = '';
$countDinner = array();
$countConfirmation = array();
//Prepare an array of requests so it can be passed back to the controller
foreach ($invitations as $invitation) {

        $countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']] = isset($countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']]) ? $countDinner[$invitation['dinner_id']] + 1 : 1;
        $countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] = isset($countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']]) ? $countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] + 1 : 1;

        //If the date changes then assign yes, this is used on front end to display date on top of requests
        if (strtotime($invitation['dinner_date']) > $lastDinnerDate) {
            $newDate = 'yes';
        } else {
            $newDate = 'no';
        }

        $lastDinnerDate = strtotime($invitation['dinner_date']);

        $dinnerDetails[] = array(
            'request_id' => $invitation['request_id'],
            'dinner_id' => $invitation['dinner_id'],
            'dinner_name' => $invitation['dinner_name'],
            'dinner_date' => $invitation['dinner_date'],
            'host_id' => $invitation['host_id'],
            'new_dinner' => $newDate,
        );

}

foreach ($dinnerDetails as &$dinnerDetail) {
    $dinnerDetail['requestCount'] = $countDinner[$dinnerDetail['dinner_id']];
    $dinnerDetail['confirmationCount'] = $countConfirmation[$dinnerDetail['host_id']];
}
```

The problem I am having is in the code below

```
$countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] = isset($countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']]) ? $countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] + 1 : 1;
```

I need to update this code in a such a way that it takes `dinner_id` into account as well so the result 'confirmationCount' i get is linked with the dinner. Right now it looks for the `host_id` and returns the result regardless of if the confirmation is linked with the right dinner or not.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you only want `$countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']]` to go up if both `dinner_id` and the `host_id` is set?

Comment: @Epodax yes you are correct and it is already doing that, but it is not considering `dinner_id` for example right now the `countConfirmation` that i get for `dinner_id => 36` is `4` whereas it should be `2`. Reason it is giving 4 is because its counting the same `host_id` for other dinners too

Comment: @FrayneKonok i dont think this is what i need

Comment: What you want to do by creating `$dinnerDetail`???

Comment: @FrayneKonok after creating it, the data gets displayed on front end

Comment: Check this and let me know: [https://3v4l.org/r1Abl](https://3v4l.org/r1Abl), based on **What i am trying to do is count the number of confirmed dinners.**.

Comment: @FrayneKonok this i already have, what i need is Dinner ID 36 was confirmed by 2 people and Dinner ID 35 was confirmed by 2 people. please note that there are going to be several dinners, i dont need count of confirmation of all dinners i need confirmation count dinner by dinner

Comment: @FrayneKonok your and my output is giving 4 confirmations but it actually 2 confirmation for dinner 36 and 2 for dinner 35, the output should be separate not combined, you will notice `host_id` and `dinner_id` are set for 4 dinners out of 5, out of which 2 are dinner id 26 and the other two are dinner id 35, so i need to seperate output

Comment: also this: `$dinnerDetails = array_count_values(array_column($invitations, 'dinner_id'));`

Comment: something like: [https://3v4l.org/Sbqbs](https://3v4l.org/Sbqbs)

Comment: @FrayneKonok issue has been resolved thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is based on multidimensional arrays. So, you are writing info to `$countConfirmation` in way of `$countConfirmation[77][36]` where `77` is `host_id` and `36` is `dinner_id` and in second loop you exactly knows how many dinners with `id=36`  where ordered by `host=77`, so just adding this info to array.

Kind of fast approach is change:

```
$countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] = isset($countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']]) ? $countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']] + 1 : 1;
```

to

```
$countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']][$invitation['dinner_id']] = isset($countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']][$invitation['dinner_id']]) ? $countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']][$invitation['dinner_id']] + 1 : 1;
```

---

After this changes you will receive double ranged array kind of :

```
[ "77" : 
    [ 
        "36"  : "2",
        "35"  : "2"
    ],

  "othe_host_id" : 
    [
        "other_dinner_id"  : "count_of_orders",
        "other_dinner_id_2"  : "count_of_orders_2",
    ],  
]
```

---

And in your second loop instead of:

```
$dinnerDetail['confirmationCount'] = $countConfirmation[$dinnerDetail['host_id']];
```

Make this, for checking info by 2 params, `host_id` and `dinner_id` :

```
$dinnerDetail['confirmationCount'] = $countConfirmation[$dinnerDetail['host_id']][$dinnerDetail['dinner_id']];
```

Comment: can you please explain the changes a bit, it seems to be giving the same result

Comment: the first change is throwing a notice `Notice: Undefined index: dinner_id`

Comment: @Saadia for what variable?

Comment: it is for `[$invitation['dinner_id']]` which you are using in `$countConfirmation[$invitation['host_id']][$invitation['dinner_id']]`

Comment: It means that you have some array without `dinner_id` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113415/discussion-between-xaqwerx-and-saadia).

Comment: nope, every array has `dinner_id`, there is no array without `dinner_id` otherwise it wont be in array